# Flash internet browser AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, web

Does a flash browser [control] exist? If not part of the Flash platform, then an open source (free of charge) implementation is prefered.

Comment: This is a legitimate question, and the given answer proves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to browse the web through Flash is by using the built in `StageWebView` component. Unfortunately, this is for Adobe AIR projects only (so you couldn't use this component with a SWF on a web page).

See [`StageWebView`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html)

Comment: It is worth mentioning Adobe Air comes bundled with webkit.

Comment: For desktop apps, yes. It uses WebKit. But it is an older version of WebKit and it cannot be trusted to render everything entirely correctly. For mobile devices, it uses the built in WebView (or equivalent) classes to display content, so you are actually displaying a chrome-less browser window within the app.